# Return string after match

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I return a string AFTER a match?

Here is my string
`"blahblah/blah/Content/Snapshot/Engines_Running"`

I want to search for `"/Content/Snapshot/"` but match `"Engines_Running"`

I tried this regex from another post but it doesn't seem to work
`[\n\r].*/Content/Snapshot/\s*([^\n\r]*)`

Comment: A similar regex - [`.*?/Content/Snapshot/\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/lZ1iK4/1) - can be used in a `Regex.Replace` function to remove all matched text and keep only what you want.

Comment: Currently using visual basic

Comment: @plsbegental VB.NET, VBA, or VB? They are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `[\n\r]` requires a newline symbol to be the first character in the input string. It is not the case with `"blahblah/blah/Content/Snapshot/Engines_Running"`, thus it does not match.

You can use a similar regex in a `Regex.Replace` method:

```
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex(".*?/Content/Snapshot/\s*") 
Console.WriteLine(MyRegex.Replace("blahblah/blah/Content/Snapshot/Engines_Running", ""))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qze1Vz)

Or another regex matching approach with a negated character class:

```
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("/Content/Snapshot/\s*([^/]*)") 
Console.WriteLine(MyRegex.Match("blahblah/blah/Content/Snapshot/Engines_Running").Groups(1).Value)
```

[Another demo](http://ideone.com/ABbvVR)

The `.*?` pattern will match everything before `/Content/Snapshot/`.

A non-regex way is to use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
str = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uj6QdA)

Comment: When downvoting, please leave feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex pattern `(?<=prefix)find` that matches a position following a prefix. In your case:

```
(?<=/Content/Snapshot/)\w+
```

`\w+` matches words containing letters, underscores and digits.